# High Water Map of Mars

Tags: mars

Based upon data available now, what would a map of mars have looked like at the peak (high) water level period.  If such a projected map is available could someone post a copy or a reference to same.  If other maps showing projections at times of reduced water levels are available these would also be of interest.

Would be interested to see if it is projected that Perseverence would be under water at it's present location.  Would also be interesting to see where projected beaches might be expected (looking for wave action effects on shoreline rocks) relative to Perseverence location.

thanks for any insights,       tom kosvic

Comment: Have you seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_ocean_hypothesis ?

Comment: You don't need a high water map of Mars to determine how much Perseverance would be under water. With *Mars trek*, https://trek.nasa.gov/mars/  , using the elevation tool, you can see that the rover is at - 2570 m. right now. With this interactive map, https://esa.int/Science_Exploration/Space_Science/Mars_Express/An_interactive_map_to_explore_Jezero_crater you can find out that the outflow channel is at about - 2380 m. So Perseverance would be about 200 m. under water. The height of the shoreline is probably the same as that of this channel.

Comment: thanks, with the ocean level discussion in ref of first comment, i can get an idea of suspected ocan levels.  the ref to nasa app "trek" is also excellent.  I was unaware of this app.  All should look at it.